# How can i MySQL FullText Search with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, full-text-search

i tried :

> models.Doctor.findAll({
> where: Sequelize.literal(`MATCH (fname, lname) AGAINST(ali)`)});
>
> table:

```js
> CREATE TABLE `doctors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci;
```

and table alter is

> ALTER TABLE `doctors`
> ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
> ALTER TABLE `doctors` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `fname` (`fname`);
> ALTER TABLE `doctors` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `lname` (`lname`);

when i tried to execute following query i gote belowe error :

```js
models.Doctor.findAll({
  where: Sequelize.literal(`MATCH (fname, lname) AGAINST(ali)`)
});
```

error:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
> at Query.formatError
> any body can help?(model and query example please)

Comment: It sounds like your table doesn't have a `FULLTEXT` index on the columns you're trying to match. Can you show the schema to confirm? Edit your question and include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for that table, trimmed and edited as necessary. Note the `\G` execution instead of `;` in the shell helps a lot with that.

Comment: my table has FULLTEXT index on relative column.

Comment: You'll need to add it to `fname` and `lname` if you want to search those like you're doing.

Comment: thanks finally i got it!.